# Can't access specific data in jsonfile - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encoding

I have this json file :

```
{
projects: [
    {
        projectId: 3
        projectName: "Complexe hotelier croisette",
        workflow: "en cours",
        realCalendars: [
            {
                id: 29,
                start: 1630590443000
                end: 1648475243000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        scheduledCalendars: [
            {
                id: 30,
                start: 1630590443000
                end: 1646059643000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        lastPlanningModif: 1639320443000
        planned: 164,
        actual: 142,
        remaining: 25,
        resourceTaskNumber: 1,
        projectTaskNumber: 18,
        leaderId: 8,
        resourceIds: [8, 7, 6],
        dashbordField: 3,
        dashbordTendency: 1,
        weatherComments: [
            {
                message: "weather 5",
                date: 1645195643000
                source: 1
                taskId:0
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 8,
                messageId: 31,
                messageParentId: 32
            },
            {
                message: "weather 6",
                date: 1643813243000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 8,
                messageId: 33,
                messageParentId: 34
            },
            {
                message: "weather 7",
                date: 1642776443000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 7,
                messageId: 35,
                messageParentId: 36
            },
        ],
        projectComments: [
            {
                message: "Time 3",
                date: 1642776443000
                source: 4
                taskId: 3789
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 7,
                messageId: 37,
                messageParentId: 38
            },
            {
                message: "Time 4",
                date: 1639838843000
                source: 4
                taskId: 3876
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 8,
                messageId: 39,
                messageParentId: 40
            },
            {
                message: "Time 5",
                date: 1638888443000
                source: 2
                taskId: 3258
                projectId: 3
                authorId: 8,
                messageId: 41,
                messageParentId: 42
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        projectId: 2
        projectName: "Festival de la moutarde de Dijon",
        workflow: "objectif",
        realCalendars: [
            {
                id: 23,
                start: 1682689643000
                end: 1696686443000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        scheduledCalendars: [
            {
                id: 24,
                start: 1682689643000
                end: 1696686443000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        lastPlanningModif:  1646059643000
        planned: 150,
        actual: 0,
        remaining: 150,
        resourceTaskNumber: 2,
        projectTaskNumber: 10,
        leaderId: 4,
        resourceIds: [4, 6, 7, 8],
        dashbordField: 4,
        dashbordTendency: 2,
        weatherComments: [
            {
                message: "weather 4",
                date: 1674744443000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 4,
                messageId: 25,
                messageParentId: 26
            }
        ],
        projectComments: [
        ],
    },
    {
        projectId: 1
        projectName: "Red Is Dead",
        workflow: "en cours",
        realCalendars: [
            {
                id: 9,
                start: 1642430843000
                end: 1669387643000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        scheduledCalendars: [
            {
                id: 10,
                start: 1642430843000
                end: 1666705643000
                type: 0
                remark: NULL 
                status: 0
                calendarId: NULL
            }
        ],
        lastPlanningModif: 1645109243000
        planned: 280,
        actual: 58,
        remaining: 222,
        resourceTaskNumber: 5,
        projectTaskNumber: 36,
        leaderId: 4,
        resourceIds: [4,5,6],
        dashbordField: 2,
        dashbordTendency: 3,
        weatherComments: [
            {
                message: "weather 1",
                date:  1645800443000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 4,
                messageId: 11,
                messageParentId: 12
            },
            {
                message: "weather 2",
                date: 1643986043000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 4,
                messageId: 13,
                messageParentId: 14
            },
            {
                message: "weather 3",
                date: 1643122043000
                source: 1
                taskId: 0
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 4,
                messageId: 15,
                messageParentId: 16
            },
        ],
        projectComments: [
            {
                message: "Time 1",
                date: 1642862843000
                source: 4
                taskId: 1234
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 5,
                messageId: 17,
                messageParentId: 18
            },
            {
                message: "Time 2",
                date: 1642258043000
                source: 4
                taskId: 1235
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 5,
                messageId: 19,
                messageParentId: 20
            },
            {
                message: "Task 1",
                date:  1641826043000
                source: 2
                taskId: 1234
                projectId: 1
                authorId: 5,
                messageId: 21,
                messageParentId: 22
            },
        ],
    }

],
avatars: [
    {
        resourceId: 8,
        idSource: 81,
        resourceName: "Alain Martoni",
        trigram: "AMO",
        imgBase64: ""
    },
    {
        resourceId: 4,
        idSource: 41,
        resourceName: "Odile Deray",
        trigram: "ODE",
        imgBase64: ""
    },
    {
        resourceId: 7,
        idSource: 71,
        resourceName: "Patrick Bialès",
        trigram: "PBI",
        imgBase64: " "
    },
    {
        resourceId: 5,
        idSource: 51,
        resourceName: "Serge Karamazov",
        trigram: "SKA",
        imgBase64: ""
    },
    {
        resourceId: 6,
        idSource: 61,
        resourceName: "Simon Jérémi",
        trigram: "SJE",
        imgBase64: ""
    }
]
```

}

Here I try to display specific data from the json (here I want to display what's in "projects")

```
var resp = response.body;
print("mydata : " + resp['projects'].toString());
```

Then I tried adding a jsonDecode :

```
var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
print("mydata : " + resp['projects'].toString());
```

Then jsonEncode :

```
var resp = jsonEncode(response.body);
print("mydata : " + resp['projects'].toString());
```

Then both :

```
var resp = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body));
print("mydata : " + resp['projects'].toString());
```

When I try display only "resp" it works, but it's the access to a specific part (like "projects") of the JSON that doesn't work. The only thing that work is with an int and it display the specific caractere of the index as if the JSON was read as a String.

```
var resp = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(response.body));
print("mydata : " + resp[0].toString());
//display the first caracter of the JSON
```

The thing is when I read the response of POST HTTP requests, using jsonEncode then jsonDecode works perfectly, I can then easily access any part of the JSON :

```
    var response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse(url),
            body: jsonEncode({
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": "10",
                "method": "method",
                "params": [someParams]
            })
          );
          var resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
          print("response body : " + resp['projects'].toString());
//display the "project" part of the JSON response
```

But all this doesn't work when trying to access specific parts of my first JSON file.

Is there something wrong with my JSON file ?

Thanks for helping.

**Update : commas are missing in the json, I corrected it but still the same probleme**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your JSON through a JSON formatter / validator and yes, your json was missing some commas and whatnot.

Check out this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/bedcdb934e46afc038f73a5f4bd6a0af) I created for your decoding - run it through [DartPad.Dev](https://dartpad.dev) and check out.

I made sure the JSON was a proper string before I ran it through the **jsonDecode**, then I just simply access its values like this:

```dart
  var decodedJSON = jsonDecode(json);

  print(decodedJSON['projects'].length);
  print(decodedJSON['projects'][0]['projectName']);
  print(decodedJSON['avatars'].length);
  print(decodedJSON['avatars'][0]['resourceName']);
```

I got the values I expected:

```
3
Complexe hotelier croisette
5
Alain Martoni
```

I think your issue was just badly formatted JSON coming out of the pipe. Check out the Gist and let me know.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the apostrophes to make it a proper string, I still don't get why we need to encapsulate the json with 3 pairs of apostrophes and why 1 pair couldn't make it... (I mean I get that with 3 pairs it works but I don't really get the why)